# Sum of range in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a huge issue with a coding problem I need to make. I am being asked to run a sum of numbers inside of an array and I can't get the code to run properly.

This is my code and below are the instructions of what I am being asked to run:

```
function sumOfRange(numbers){
var numbers = [1,-1,1,-1,1];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
sum += numbers[i];
}
return sum;
}

// Your Challenge:
// - Create a function named sumOfRange.
// - It accepts one parameter, called numbers, that
//   represents an array of numbers. 
//

// - In your function, sum the numbers inside the array. 
//   (Reminder: you'll need a variable to store the result.)
// - Return the result.


// Hint: You do not need to create a new array - you will be 
// looping through the parameter, which is already coming in as 
// an array.

// Someone else will be calling your function like this:
// sumOfRange([1,2,3,4,5])
// sumOfRange([-4,-5,-10,0])
```

I keep getting

#### errors saying

> You returned '1'. That isn't quite right. The sum of [1,2,3,4,5] is 15.

Any help with this would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your array is `[1,-1,1,-1,1]` not `[1,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: the numbers variable is being rewritten with `var numbers = [1,-1,1,-1,1];` and no matter the params will always output one.

Comment: I tried that before as well and it would give me the inverse error. 
"You returned '15'. That isn't quite right. The sum of [1,-1,1,-1,1] is 1."

Comment: From the instructions: "Hint: You do not need to create a new array - you will be looping through the parameter, which is already coming in as an array."

Comment: One of the main things you need to learn right now - besides reading the instructions! - is how to debug your JavaScript code. Have you used a JavaScript debugger? Every browser has one. For example, here's an [overview of the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Use that to step through your code line by line and you will quickly see what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first line of your function sumOfRange() `var numbers = [1,-1,1,-1,1]` because you are re-initializing the value of numbers, you need to use to array that is passed to the function when it is called.

```js
function sumOfRange(numbers) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(sumOfRange([1,-1,1,-1,1]));
console.log(sumOfRange([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(sumOfRange([-4,-5,-10,0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
function sum (arr) {
 return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr;
 }, 0);  
}
```

//sum(a) -> returns 15